# Force theme change as observable action

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, android-theme

I am trying to implement a theme change in Android since I need to change the look and feel of the whole application dynamically as a result of some asynchronous action.

I have several themes like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material</item>
</style>

<style name="YellowTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorYellowLight</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorYellowDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material</item>
</style>

<style name="GreenTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorGreenLight</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorGreenDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material</item>
 </style>
```

and I am using `MutableLiveData` to store some object which is used as a basis for the theme change:

```
val dayTypeDTO = MutableLiveData<DayTypeDTO>()
```

I am then observing this object and when it's value changes, I need to change the app theme:

```
cache.dayTypeDTO.observe(this, Observer { dto ->
            if (dto != null) setTheme(dto.theme)
})
```

The problem is that the theme change should happen after the view is inflated. Otherwise, it is not applied. But since I am registering the observers after the view is created and due to the dynamic change which cannot be predicted, I cannot really do it this way.

I know I can call `activity.recreate()` but this just results in an infinite loop.

Can someone suggest how to achieve this theme change so all components using `colorPrimary` are updated as a result of this observable action? Preferably other then changing them manually one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Add an onGlobalLayoutListener to your view to ensure that the layout is inflated before setting the theme on it:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener